# How to avoid the editing of a macro in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a macro in Excel. When I send it to some user, he should not be able to see the macro.

Say I have a Excel workbook sample.xls, and it has a macro button to save the workbook to the server. When some other user opens the workbook, he should not be able to edit the macro behind that button.

How do I block other users from editing the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To lock a VBA project for viewing**

Open the document, template, or database that contains the VBA project you want to protect. For Outlook or FrontPage, start Outlook or FrontPage on the computer that contains the VBA project you want to protect.

Open the Visual Basic Editor.

In the Project Explorer, right-click the project you want to protect, and then click ProjectName Properties on the shortcut menu.

On the Protection tab, select the Lock project for viewing check box, enter and confirm the password, and then click OK.

Comment: one way but easily crackable. For more advanced users (both the 'office excel hackers'(lol) and programmers it's a good practice to  create a *.dll com add-in that would store the connection string providing a better security and it would be much harder for someone to decompile the dll.

Comment: also if the security level is already dropped ( meaning that macros are always enabled ) you can close the VBE window as soon as it opens modifying the VBE winAPI

Answer (score 0):

You can password protect it. But I'd suggest you search how to do it for your specific version of MS Excel. There is a link which shows how to do it in MS Excel 2003, I think: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/protect-vba-code.htm