# Is there programming solution to lock down macro in excel from editing？

Tags: java, excel

Similar with existing question ( [How to avoid the editing of a macro in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183173/how-to-avoid-the-editing-of-a-macro-in-excel)), I want a programming solution to prevent macro from editing, do you have any idea?

Update: I found an available solution provided by Aspose.Cells. But the library has license cost which is expensive (about $10,000 for each version). Is there any other solution can do the same thing?

```
//import com.aspose.cells.Workbook
Workbook workbook = …
workbook.getVbaProject().protect(true, “test”);
…
```